# Python Kivy slows down dramatically when showing multiple images

Tags: python, image, performance, kivy

As soon as I display multiple images in kivy the app slows down dramatically. When I make images bigger by stretching the window size everything slow down too.

I'm running kivy on a chromebook with linux enabled

image file size: 4k

image file type: png

total images: 24

image widget size: 100, 100

I have a moving widget at a constant speed updated with `Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0/60.0)`. But it slows down to about half the speed and the movement is a bit jerky when the images are displayed. I tried converting the images from png-24 to png-8 but that didnt help.

Kivy version: 1.11.1

**EDIT**

I found that it was linked to a gridlayout that showed a grid of boxes:

```py
# .kv
<GridBox>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: .5, .5, .5, .1 # problom starts here!
        Line:
            width: 2
            rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height

<Grid>:

# .py

class GridBox(Widget):
    pass


class Grid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Grid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 12 #Window.width/100
        self.rows = 8 #Window.height/100
        for x in range(self.rows * self.cols):
            self.add_widget(GridBox())
```

Because the boxes have a transparency it was having trouble showing the images underneath maybe? Setting the opacity to 1 made it all speed up a lot, but still not full speed. Removing the grid alltogether made everything run normally again and removing the images and not the grid made it all run normally again too. So its still linked to the images

most of my code:

```py
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '1200')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '800')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, StringProperty  # pylint: disable=E0611
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock


class Player(Image):
    source = StringProperty("assets/player/idleRight.png")


class GridBox(Widget):
    pass


class Grid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Grid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 12 #Window.width/100
        self.rows = 8 #Window.height/100
        for x in range(self.rows * self.cols):
            self.add_widget(GridBox())


class Tile(Image):
    pass


class Tiles(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Tiles, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # open a level file with data showing where to put some images
        # e.g. level.txt:
        #     -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
        #     AA AA -- BB BB BA -- DD
        #     ...
        with open("level1.txt", "r") as level_file:
            rows = level_file.readlines()
            for row in range(len(rows)):
                cols = rows[row].split()
                print(cols)
                for box in range(len(cols)):
                    if cols[box] != "--":
                        self.add_widget(
                            Tile(source=f"assets/tiles/tile{cols[box]}.png", pos=(100 * box, Window.height - 100 - 100 * row)))


class Game(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Game, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.player = Player(y=100, center_x=self.center_x)
        self.add_widget(self.player)
        self.event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / 60.0)

    def update(self, tk):
        self.player.x += 5

class ExampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Game(size=Window.size)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ExampleApp().run()
```

```
#:kivy 1.11.1


<Player>:
    allow_stretch: True
    keep_ratio: True
    
<GridBox>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: .5, .5, .5, .1
        Line:
            width: 2
            rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height

<Grid>:


<Tile>:
    allow_stretch: True
    keep_ratio: True

<Tiles>:

<Game>:
    Image:
        source: "assets/bg.png"
        keep_ratio: True
        allow_stretch: True
        width: root.width
        height: root.width
        center: root.center
    Grid:
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
    Tiles:
```

Comment: Can you post a minimal example app to make sure you haven't done something wrong? Also don't use pygame as your image loader, make sure kivy is running with SDL2.

Comment: Ok thanks. I've added some code to my question and i've managed to force SDL2 using this answer: (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60115072/1197968). I dont get the warnings anymore